# How to watch variable in code::blocks?

Tags: codeblocks

My watch

[image]

and this

[image]

string

How to display like the picture?

Answer (score 0):

To display the Watches window, tou can open the Debug menu, pause over the "Debugging Windows" option, and select "Watches" from the submenu that pops up.

The Watches menu always pops up small and sits over your code, so you may want to expand it or dock it above the logs.

The Watches menu will always show program arguments and local variables, but not global variables.  For structure and class variables, you can click on the tiny "+" by the variable name to see all of the properties.  Char* variables will be shown as strings, but it will not give you the properties of a class or struct that you have a pointer to.

To see global variables or follow pointers, click in the left cell in the lowest row and type the variable name you want to see.  You can also type out function calls to evaluate them, but it will not be able to run inline functions.

If this doesn't answer your question, you might clarify what you want displayed, and which the two pictures do you want it to be like.